# How can Position property in CSS be used to prevent scroll-able section

Tags: css

When info popup is clicked, it turns into scroll-able section. I need that this popup takes up some extra space below without new scroll section.

[image: This is Normal Preview]

[image: This is when info popup icon is clicked. This is with CSS Position Absolute, where a new scroll appears in middle and the half of popup hides up, also complete CSS code for this is below.]

In above picture, new scroll at center left side appears and the half of popup hides up, which I don't want.

I tried Position: Static that gives the exact behavior I need, that is no scroll and popup now takes complete space till down but this changes the relative position of Info icon to top middle of popup, which is not expected. As show below:

[image: Trial-1]

```
.popupleftalign .popupcontrolbackground > span:first-of-type > div:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 250px;
    border-collapse: initial !important;
    border-radius: 6px;
    top: -2px;
    right: 0px;
    max-width: 600px;
    line-height: 22px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    vertical-align: top !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
    z-index: 10000;
    color: black !important;
    word-break: keep-all;
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: -webkit-max-content;
 }
```

I need that this popup doesn't hides up i.e. no scroll separate scroll section for this. Either it comes top of rest of section or it takes extra space below without hiding up itself.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: I've provided everything as per my understanding that makes the issue clear, If you need some more clarification at some point please let me know.

Comment: _“If you need some more clarification please let me know.”_ - I just did, by referring you to an extended explanation of what you are supposed to present, to enable us to help with your problem. No one here can tell what causes the problem, as long as we don’t even know what HTML you are applying this CSS to … (Only thing we can tell, is that you are likely creating invalid HTML – nesting `div` into `span` is not allowed.)

Comment: there must a height defined on this scroll-able section, make that auto or remove height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon struggling some more, found out that parent to this section (that contains info icon) had Overflow as Auto `overflow: auto;`. That's why upon increased content inside this parent created scrolling enabled. Changing parent's Overflow to Visible `overflow: visible;` (that's default option also), doesn't create scroll thing and just overlaps other content as a popup is expected to do.
So, basically I'd given incomplete information unintentionally. So, apologies for that.